# Visual Basic Macro in Outlook 2010, saving to a specific folder?

Tags: vba, outlook, vcf-vcard

I am working with converting people from an older email client to Outlook 2010. Trying to convert the contacts over efficiently can be a pain, so we have some code that does the grunt work for us. The process I am using works to a point. I have all the VCards from the contacts and found source code for a macro online that imports all these VCards. The problem is that it defaults to the "Contacts" Address Book. Here is the code:

```
Sub OpenSaveVCard()

    Dim objWSHShell As IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShell
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim colInsp As Outlook.Inspectors
    Dim strVCName As String
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fsDir As Scripting.Folder
    Dim fsFile As Scripting.File
    Dim vCounter As Integer

    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fsDir = fso.GetFolder("C:\VCARDS")

    For Each fsFile In fsDir.Files
        strVCName = "C:\VCARDS\" & fsFile.Name
        Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set colInsp = objOL.Inspectors
        If colInsp.Count = 0 Then
                Set objWSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
                objWSHShell.Run strVCName
                Set colInsp = objOL.Inspectors

                If Err = 0 Then
                    Do Until colInsp.Count = 1
                    DoEvents
                    Loop
                    colInsp.Item(1).CurrentItem.Save
                    colInsp.Item(1).Close olDiscard
                    Set colInsp = Nothing
                    Set objOL = Nothing
                    Set objWSHShell = Nothing
                End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I'm not overly familiar with Visual Basic and writing macros, is there a way where I can specify which Address Book to save to? For example, if I have an Address Book named "Test". Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can use `Session.AddressBook` (found [here](http://excel.bigresource.com/Track/excel-51GSVyaM/))

You can access the AddressBook with this kind of code:

```
Set olkRecipients = cdoSession.AddressBook(, "Global Address List", 0, False)
```

On my version (2007), the property i found was `Session.AddressLists` and i couldn't find the `Addressbook` one. Have a try and see which one works.